# npm start creates only server only at localhost when building Eleventy blog

Tags: node.js, server, eleventy, static-site-generation

I want to know what lacks in order to command `npm start` to launch a site externally.

I've added
  `"scripts": { "start": "eleventy --serve", "build":  "eleventy" },`
into package.json as instructed. In tutorial it launches both locally and externally but not in my situation.

Comment: What do you mean with "launch a site externally"?

Comment: It means to have server not only at localhost, but external server as well. 
CL says `[11ty] Server at http://localhost:8080/` but I would like it to have 4 lines, where it shows IP address for external server.
I already deployed the website but it didn't change

Comment: So, you set it up on a different machine as the external server? Or do you want your application to be accessible from outside your own network?